# After calling start( ), why does the thread’s constructor returns to main( ), without being the control forwarded to the run() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here is an example that creates a new thread and starts it running:

```
class NewThread implements Runnable {
Thread t; 
NewThread() {
   // Create a new, second thread
   t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
   System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
   t.start(); // Start the thread
}
// This is the entry point for the second thread.
public void run() {
  try {
   for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
   System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
   Thread.sleep(500);
   }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
  }
  System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
 }
}
```

Now consider the other thread(main),
After the new thread is created, it will not start running until you call its start( ) method,
which is declared within Thread. In essence, start( ) executes a call to run( ).

```
public class ThreadDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    new NewThread(); // create a new thread
    try {
        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
    }
    System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
}
```

}

Inside NewThread’s constructor, a new Thread object is created by the following statement:

```
t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
```

Passing this as the first argument indicates that you want the new thread to call the run( )
method on this object. 
Next, start( ) is called, which starts the thread of execution beginning at the run( ) method. 
This causes the child thread’s for loop to begin. 
After calling start( ), NewThread’s constructor returns to main( ). 
When the main thread resumes, it enters its for loop. 
Both threads continue running, sharing the CPU, until their loops finish.

After calling start( ),  why does the thread’s constructor returns to main( ), without being the control forwarded to the run() method?

Comment: You have threads, multiple threads which run, kind of, concurrently. So why shouldn't the control be returned. The whole idea of multiple threads is that they can do things concurrently.

Comment: 'In essence, start( ) executes a call to run( )' - NO, IT DOES NOT!

Comment: @Martin James: I don't consider HERBERT SCHILDT to be wrong on that...or else do justify with a detailed one. I would be far more happy.

Comment: Since it is not possible to call a thread, HS is totally wrong for any sane definition of 'call'.

Comment: Threads are given execution by the OS.  The thread that creates the new thread does not, and cannot, provide any execution for the new thread.  The code of the new thread is typically not even called by the OS to make it run: it is interrupt-returned to, just as if it had been running before and been interrupted.  The stack-based function-call mechanism and the creation and provision of execution by the OS to a new thread, (which has its own stack), are so orthogonal that HS has taken a right-angle into a wall.

Comment: @Martin James: Your answer makes sense to me. From oracle docs: start() - 
Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread. I think HS is referring to JVM here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`start()` starts a new thread. The control of that new thread reaches your `run()` method. Your expectation for the control in the thread which executed `start()` to reach `run()` is illogical and, if it were met, would be self-defeating.

Comment: I like your answer. Debugging it confused me, which in essence takes back to the point from where it was initiated. One more point i would like to clear. Marko, can i say that from within the main thread(void main()), another thread got started. I know they are running concurrently, following their own independent path of executions.

Comment: I have gone through examples which regards main() as a thread. But inside there is no mention of start() and run() methods. As per my understanding, the JVM must be responsible for that. Am i correct or is it completely not into my mind.

Comment: main() is a method, not a thread. It is the method called from the main thread as a part of JVM startup.

Answer (score 2):

Read the Javadoc of `Thread.start`:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

The difference between the `start()` and `run()` methods is that the first one creates a new thread and this newly created thread will internally execute the `run` method. Once the new thread is created, control is returned to the caller thread to continue and the result is that two threads running in parallel.

On the other hand, calling `run` will simply execute the method in the same thread (no new thread is created).

Comment: "...the second invokes the run method in the caller thread." That's going to be confusing to a newbie who has not yet learned the difference between _thread_ (a path of execution through the code), and `Thread` (a java class with methods that create and manage _threads_.)

Comment: @manouti: any valuable suggestions on Martin James part mentioned above